# Firefox : Open Recently Closed Tabs Not Working

Tags: firefox

I am trying to use `Ctrl+SHIFT+T` to open a recently closed tab. But this option is not working as this option has been disabled in firefox.

I googled for a possible solution. One the accepted solutions was to configure the options of `browser.sessionstore.max_tabs_undo.` and `browser.sessionstore.max_windows_undo` by going into `about:config`. But I still don't know as to what values should I use for these.

Can someone help me out with this problem? This seems to be a problem with updated firefox.

Comment: You're not in private browsing mode, are you?

Comment: no I dont think so ..

Comment: I installed an extension `Undo Closed Tab` and now its working .. I can't figure out a possible reason for why it was not working earlier.

Comment: If you are stating that `this option is not working as this option has been disabled in firefox` then logic would dictate that you are viewing the correct screen to enable it as well, no?

Answer (score 0):

I just change the value of `browser.sessionstore.max_tabs_undo` to 10, and the feature works again.